# Angualr4, Wait after 3 invalid login attempts

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am working on an login form in Angular4. I would like to implement a 30 seconds wait (by disabling button) after entering 3 invalid credentials. After the next 3 invalid attempts, waiting time will just double, 60 seconds, 120 seconds so on and so forth. I initiatialized a counter and decrement it in each invalid form submissions. And used setTimeInterval like:

```
initCounter() {
    this.intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
        let count = this.counter;
        if (count > 0) {
            this.counter = count - 1;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

However I couldn't complete this task as expected.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Off the top of my head, instead of decrementing the counter, you can increment it. Then check if it's a multiple of 3 and if it is use that as a multiplier eg. if the counter is 6, 6/3=2... then 2x30seconds gives you 60 second timeout. 9/3 means 3x30seconds and so on. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a side warning: disabling the button (alone) is not sufficient.
You need to also implement the waiting on the server.
Since anyone trying to brute force your site is going to be firing HTTP requests at it directly. Not using your frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could done it like

```
 setLoginCounter(loginForm) {
      this.loginCounter += 1;
      localStorage.setItem('logCount', this.loginCounter.toString());

      if (this.loginCounter % 3 === 0) {
                this.counter = 30 * (Math.pow(2, (this.loginCounter / 3) - 1));
      }

    }
```